# What is the PostgreSQL Equivalent of Oracle's FLOAT(126)?

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes

I need to migrate some data from Oracle to Postgres. I am not finding an exact equivalent to Oracles `FLOAT(126)` (126 binary digits). Postgres has a max of `FLOAT(54)` (54 binary digits).

What is the equivalent of Oracle's `FLOAT(126)` in PostgreSQL?

Comment: What do you mean with binary digits? Postgres` float uses 32 bit ("binary digits") and `double precision` uses 64 bits. Neither of them allow to specify a precision. If you mean 126 decimal digits (precision), you need to go for `numeric`

Comment: Try one of the variable precision numeric types in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-numeric.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name With “binary digits” I am exactly quoting the docs of both Oracle and PostgreSQL. I presume they mean storage bits.

Comment: Just use `numeric`. All Oracle numbers are `NUMBER` under the hood, `FLOAT` is no exception.